# How to trigger grid cell event when selecting associated store record?

Tags: javascript, extjs, bryntum-scheduler

I have a grid (I'm using Bryntum scheduler) where I have a text search where I'm using scrollEventIntoView() to highlight the found record.

I would then like to trigger a click event for the found item. I guess the issue is I really don't know how to translate the selected item in the store to the selected item in the grid.

I'm a little confused as to the difference of store.getAt() vs. getSelectionModel.select(). (and if someone could point me to a good article on the selection model, that would be appreciated as well)

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var searchIndex = ds.eventStore.find('DealTitle',mySearch)
var SearchRec = ds.eventStore.getAt(searchIndex);
ds.getView().scrollEventIntoView(SearchRec, true);
```

...all is good there. What I'd like to do next is something like this:

```
var selCell = ds.getSelectionModel().select(__WHAT GOES HERE?__);
```

or this:

```
SearchRec.fireEvent('click');
```

...but I seem to be missing a reference to the grid cell I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SearchRec goes there :)

```
var selCell = ds.getSelectionModel().select(SearchRec);
```

UPDATE

I've just understand that you are probably using extjs3.

In Extjs3 you can select cell like this

```
var index = grid.store.find(('DealTitle',mySearch));
//second param is index of column
grid.getSelectionModel().select(index, 0);
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/35E5E/1/)